# Python Celery Threads, Workers and vCPUs

Tags: python, django, multithreading, rabbitmq, celery

We have written an application which sends out billing information by email to over 200,000 customers of our customer.

Presently we were using a batch processing program that takes well over 2 days to send out all emails in a sequential manner.

We have shifted the entire program to Celery, and we have already seen some remarkable improvement on a regular 2 worker load.

Has anyone benchmarked Celery?

Documentation says that number fo workers must equal to the number of CPUs for performance. Suppose we virtualize the server and set up 32 vCPUs over a physical 8 core server, can we run it at 32 threads in concurrency?

The mails are shipped through different mail servers, the server only runs Rabbit MQ, Celery and the application.

Please advise the right number of workers and threads and vcpus to avoid unnecessary queueing, and delaying.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You will need to understand what you are doing, and probably measure it yourself

Longer:

The main question is if your tasks are CPU bound or I/O (network/disk) bound.  If your tasks are CPU bound (probably stuff like generating templates, images), you won't get any improvements by adding workers.  However most chances are you are on I/O bound (network) tasks, and if you are waiting for network acknowledgments, and there is no bottleneck in the mail server etc, you will probably be able to gain higher results by using more workers.

To understand this much better, I highly recommend walking slowly through David Beazley's eye opening presentation here: [An Introduction to Python Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/concurrent/).  This does not cover Celery and Tornado, but gives an excellent overview of the underlying technology and problems, and lays out the solutions (with examples) as well.

Comment: Thanks. There are no network waits. Everything is more or less I/O Bound and Database bound.Is there any ratio on vCPus versus the number of concurrency threads? I am as per your suggestion going slowly over the presentation

Comment: If it is SQLDB bound (i.e., your tasks write to the DB directly, and these causes delays in the process), you might want to consider reading everything in the process creating the tasks, sending it to many workers via the event Q, and returning the result via a message Q result backend, to be written much later to the DB by one sequential DB writing worker.  This way you can make your tasks 100% network bound and create much more workers, or rewrite it to be completely async (e.g. use tornado), and use one worker per cpu.  Anyway, there is no "magic number" and you should see the slideshow :-)

Comment: If your tasks are I/O bound then you can also use the eventlet/gevent pools: `celery worker -l info -P gevent -c 1000`.  If you have 32 CPUs then you can use celery multi to take advantage of them: `celery multi start 32 -P eventlet -c 100` for 32 worker processes with 100 concurrent threads each.